# What is the meaning of 串串儿？

Tags: translation, meaning, food

The only translation I can find has to do with strings...?

I heard this phrase when someone was speaking about 四川菜, is this related to 火锅？ Is this phrase a joke of sorts about the Sichuan dialect ?

Haha, Thank you for your answer(s) : )

Comment: look up 串串香: http://baike.baidu.com/link?url=3BWqiwrcwaJBErPdDlkcAkVCNEeUY_l2Lp__uolred04kkxoymZzRx48u4BUbFHEiLldTAbmMam3mVZ9_LUnp9igvF9BP_Xxyr28F75SJ1W

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read 串 then 串儿, a bit like 麻辣烫 on sticks!

[image: 串串儿]

Comment: Cool - thank you! I get it. Like a kabob!!

Comment: It can mean kabobs or to make kabobs  depends upon how you read it.串1串儿 means to make，串4串儿 means kabobs

Comment: for picture see （欲看到张照片，请点击）e。g。 http://www.xinshipu.com/shipu/%E4%B8%B2%E4%B8%B2%E5%84%BF/